# Setting parent button disabled?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, parent-child

So i have a script that creates buttons, and a script that makes these buttons interactable on certain scenarios.

Problem is, in the script that creates the buttons, 2 of the buttons it creates have more child buttons underneath them. With my following code i can easily make those childbuttons interactable whenever i want, but it wont recognize the parents. I realize why (because my list checks for childs) but I have no clue on how to fix this. Make a second list for the parent buttons or? Code is below.

```
MenuButton[] MenuButtons = _selectionEditMenuPanel.GetComponentsInChildren<MenuButton>(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < MenuButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            if (MenuButtons[i].name == "edit_group" || MenuButtons[i].name == "edit_ungroup")
            {
                if (_selection.SelectedPageObject.IsGroup())
                {
                    MenuButtons[i].GetComponent<MenuButton>().menuButton.GetComponent<TestButton>().Interactable = true;
                    if (!((PageObjectGroup)_selection.SelectedPageObject).IsTempGroup)
                    {
                        MenuButtons[i].title.text = TranslationSystem.Request("edit_ungroup");
                        MenuButtons[i].name = "edit_ungroup";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MenuButtons[i].title.text = TranslationSystem.Request("edit_group");
                        MenuButtons[i].name = "edit_group";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MenuButtons[i].title.text = TranslationSystem.Request("edit_group");
                    MenuButtons[i].name = "edit_group";
                    MenuButtons[i].GetComponent<MenuButton>().menuButton.GetComponent<testButton>().Interactable = false;

                }
            }

            if (MenuButtons[i].name == "edit_crop")
            {
                //Only make crop button interactive when pageobject bitmap is selected 
                MenuButtons[i].GetComponent<MenuButton>().menuButton.GetComponent<testButton>().Interactable = _selection.SelectedPageObject is PageObjectBitmap;
            }

            //TODO Make this work with edit align? It works with other buttons.
            if (MenuButtons[i].name == "edit_align")
            {
               if (!_selection.SelectedPageObject.IsGroup())
               {
                    MenuButtons[i].GetComponent<MenuButton>().menuButton.GetComponent<testButton>().Interactable = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   MenuButtons[i].GetComponent<MenuButton>().menuButton.GetComponent<testButton>().Interactable = true;
               }
            }
```

It works for everything except the last check, edit_align(this is a button with childs underneath it) I'll post the general setup of the button creating script below, but NOTE: I cant edit that scripts, it's not mine so please don't advise me to edit that.

```
private static MenuItem _selectionEditMenu = new MenuItem(Resources.Load<Sprite>("Edit_128"))
    { new MenuItem(Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Icons/Align_Left_1_128"), "edit_align", true, true, null)
        {
            new MenuItem(Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Icons/Distribute_Horizontally_128"), "edit_align_distribute_evenly"
            new MenuItem(Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Icons/Uniform_Height_128"), "edit_align_uniform_height"
```

I can reach the edit_align_Distribute_evenly & the Uniform height, but not the parent above called: edit_align.

NOTE: I left away some syntax etc cause of company names in there. So don't worry about syntax not being correct.
Thanks, every help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Winforms: _two of the buttons it creates have more child buttons underneath them._ A child is always on top of the parent.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean? I'm working with Unity/Monobehavior. Sorry if I forgot to tagg it correctly. I don't post often.

Comment: First use `else if` in your `for` loop. Second. Is your button really named "edit_align"?

Comment: I really don't understand what your asking, maybe because I haven't had my coffee, but you've do know that `transform.parent` and `GetComponentsInParent`? (see what I mean , "you've do")

Comment: @Morasiu "NOTE: I left away some syntax etc cause of company names in there" Did you read that?

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to point you to check if you passed correct name.

Comment: @Morasiu Fair enough, Thanks though. I fixed it another way atm, since suggested ways here didn't work. But thanks for the help!